# How to assign variable value to constant in perl?

Tags: perl

I have following code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;

use constant ARRAY => "XCC320G";
print ARRAY;
print "Enter ur choice\n";
chomp($choice = <STDIN>);
ARRAY=>$choice;
print ARRAY;
```

Currently my code is with respect to constant. Now I want to make it generic so I have to give variable value to the constant. Is there any way to do this in perl?

Comment: Either it's a variable and you can assign values to it or it's a constant and you can't. Pick one.

Comment: As per @wurtel's comment, the question doesn't make sense as posed. I have been recently told by one of the site moderators that questions like this shouldn't be migrated, even if they are about programming. I note that there are currently 4 votes to migrate it to StackOverflow. One more and it will get migrated. To future visitors: please don't vote to migrate this to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Welcome to programming and Perl.  Try this website to help you get started: http://learn.perl.org/  It would be a really great idea for you to find a copy of a book like "Learning Perl" if you can.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you're turning on warnings twice - once with the '-w' flag on the shebang line, and once with the 'use warnings' line. Modern practice is generally just to use the "use warnings" method, older code and tutorials will use the other. Also you may want to look at "use strict"

Answer (score 3):

The definition of a constant includes the fact that you cannot assign a different value to it later on. If you wish to be able to assign to it then it should not have been a constant.

Answer (score 2):

The point of a CONSTANT is that it's ... CONSTANT. E.g. not changing.

A constant that changes ... isn't, it's a variable. Of course, you've also called it ARRAY when it only contains a single value, so that doesn't make much sense either.

So in your code instead, you could:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $value = "XCC320G";
print $value,"\n";
print "Enter your choice\n";
chomp(my $choice = <STDIN>);
$value = $choice;
print $value;
```

If you do want to treat it as an array (although your *probably* mean `LIST`) - you can do:

```
my @list_of_values = ( "XCC320G" );
print join ( "\n", @list_of_values ), "\n";
print "Enter your choice\n";
chomp(my $choice = <STDIN>);
push ( @list_of_values, $choice );
print join ( "\n", @list_of_values ), "\n";
```